# " a namespace name is not allowed" error in javacpp

Tags: c++, cuda, javacpp

I am trying to use [this](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/wiki/ThrustAndCUDA) example in my java app which is build using maven. 
pom.xml include

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>javacpp</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-jar</argument>       <argument>/home/JCuda/javacpp.jar</argument>
                            <argument>-classpath</argument> <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}:/home/JCuda/jcuda-0.5.0.jar:/home/JCuda/jcusparse-0.5.0.jar</argument>
                            <argument>-d</argument>         <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}/lib/</argument>
                            <argument>-properties</argument>    <argument>linux-x86_64-cuda</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When nvcc is compiling .cu file it shows error
**/home/TestWebapp6/target/classes/lib/jniCudaOps.cu(1154): error: a namespace name is not allowed**
which in code is this line

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_skenzo_cuda_CudaOps_copy(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject arg0, jobject arg1, jobject arg2) {
    thrust* ptr0 = arg0; //line showing the first error
    thrust* ptr1 = arg1;
....
```

Any clues?

Comment: thrust is the name of the C++ namespace which holds the CUDA thrust template library, so obviously it is syntactically invalid to declare a pointer in the way the code snippet you have shows. But there is so much abstraction the in code generation and build process that I don't see how anyone can answer this question as it is written.

Comment: that file (jniCudaOps.cu) has been generated by library itself. I can't paste the whole code here but my code is exactly same as the link given with added maven dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a question better suited to the javacpp mailing list. Check out [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/javacpp-project/jgfrY11sdFg/33hDjuZLIKEJ) for example.